# Call to getRedirectResult after authenticating is very slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use firebase auth using the redirect mechanism, problem is after successfully authenticating I have to wait for getRedirectResult() to be called. Problem is it is extremely slow and no amount loading indicators can fix this terrible UX. I have posted a demo of the experience below. Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

https://giphy.com/gifs/3JZdd8xDbfkB3RJlJ0

Comment: also posted on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1499

Comment: same issue here

Comment: In my experience, the entire Firebase Auth solution including client, UI, and Admin SDK are super slow.

Comment: same here almost 2 years later :/ At this time I need to add loader :O

Comment: Still slow in october 2021